# rodar o puppeteer as 8 da manha todos os dias

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

opa, eu sei o básico de javascript, mas com muita pesquisa eu consegui criar uma aplicação para pegar algumas informações de uns sites e fazer uns cálculos. é um sistema simples pra um amigo que é trader e precisa fazer esses calculos manualmente no excel.

seguinte, o codigo seguinte pega as informações dos sites e salva num json (no caso 3)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://br.advfn.com/investimentos/futuros/di-depositos-interfinanceiros/cotacoes',{
    waitUntill: 'load',
    timeout: 0
  });
  
  const textNode = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    const nodeText = document.querySelector(".even.first").innerText;
    const text = [nodeText];
    
    return text
  });

  fs.writeFile('arreglo2.json', JSON.stringify(textNode), err =>{
    if (err) throw new Error ('algo deu errado')
      console.log('deu certo')
  })

})();

//************************************************************************/
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://br.tradingview.com/symbols/TVC-DXY/',{
    waitUntill: 'load',
    timeout: 0
  });
  

  const textNode = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    const nodeText = document.querySelector(".tv-symbol-price-quote__change-value").innerText;
    const text = [nodeText];
    
    return text
  });

  fs.writeFile('arreglo.json', JSON.stringify(textNode), err =>{
    if (err) throw new Error ('algo deu errado')
      console.log('deu certo')
  })

})();

/**********vai pegar a cotação do fechamento do colar */

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://br.advfn.com/bolsa-de-valores/fx/USDBRL/cotacao',{
    waitUntill: 'load',
    timeout: 0
  });
  

  const textNode = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    const nodeText = document.querySelector(".qs-current-price").innerText;
    const text = [nodeText];
    
    return text
  });

  fs.writeFile('cotacaoFechamento.json', JSON.stringify(textNode), err =>{
    if (err) throw new Error ('algo deu errado')
      console.log('deu certo')
  })

})();
```

quando eu abro o terminal e dou node index.js ai ele roda de boa, cria o json e tudo, ai quando eu dou refresh na página já ta tudo calculado.

so que eu queria saber agora como faço pra fazer o index.js rodar exatamente as 820 todo dia.
pq meu amigo precisa dos dados as 830h quando o mercado abrir.

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Essa aplicação roda num servidor? Computador do usuário? Já testou crontab? 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler estes dois posts: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Comment: então, quando eu subir para um site de hospedagem, isso caracteriza um servidor? eu só manjo de front-end, é minha primeira "aplicação" por assim dizer com algo de back-end. mas eu pretendo subir ela pra ficar disponível. hoje eu to rodando no xampp pra testar.

Answer (score -3):

Da uma pesquisada sobre a biblioteca [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), com ela você vai conseguir agendar as execuções do seu script. [Como usar](https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/agendando-tarefas-com-o-cron-para-node).

Para o agendamento do node-cron funcionar você vai precisar deixar o script executando, para isso eu gosto de usar o [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/). [Como usar](https://imasters.com.br/back-end/executando-o-pm2-e-o-node-js-em-ambientes-de-producao).

Comment: obrigado, eu tava aqui pesquisando, no caso a minha dúvida ainda é maior. por exemplo, um site estatico eu vou lá e coloco as pastas no site e em poucos segundos ele ja ta no ar. nesse caso é mais complexo né? pq tem um arquivo .js, tem json e as pastas do node. eu tenho que contratar algum tipo de serviço especifico de servidor?

Comment: Esse seu script teria que rodar separado do site porque se não ele executa só quando você abrir o site. Você teria que deixar esse script rodando em algum servidor ou até mesmo na sua máquina local e criar uma API que retorne os dados do seu arquivo JSON. No frontend você apenas chamaria essa API para buscar os dados do JSON..

Comment: tem alguma empresa que tipo presta esse serviço pra eu hospedar esse script num servidor?

Comment: Sim,  já usei o Replit pra isso, mas não sei se continua gratuito. Hoje em dia tenho alguns bots online e deixo eles rodando através do PM2 em uma EC2 na AWS, mas dai você vai ter que configurar tudo, com o replit você só jogaria o código lá dentro e botaria pra rodar o script